# instantiating array for tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray that gets instantiated with

```
_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
```

in viewDidLoad.

The user can then press an "add" button to add a row.

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"add");
    [_items addObject:@"row"];
    [self.tbl reloadData];
}
```

I have it so that when didSelectRowAtIndexPath gets called the view switches. The next view has a back button to go back to the tableview. However, once the tableview gets refreshed the list is not populated with the previous added values. Obviously this makes sense because viewDidLoad instantiates the array to null. How can I fix this? Please and Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing shouldn't happen. If you go back to a controller with a back button, viewDidLoad shouldn't be called again. You should put a log in there to see if it is being called -- if so, you're doing something wrong in your navigation.

Comment: viewDidLoad does get called upon hitting back. For my navigation I'm "ctrl-dragging" the back button from one view controller to the other as a modal switch. Is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: @user2402616 you should be using a `UINavigationController` and pushing detail view controllers onto the navigation stack, **or** displaying the detail view controllers **modally** and ***dismissing*** them, not creating a new root view controller each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't "go back" to a controller with a segue, other than an unwind segue. All other segues instantiate new controllers, so that's why viewDidLoad is called. You should either use an unwind segue, or dismiss the controller in code with `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` (assuming you presented it modally in the first place).